# Can't find SEER rating for Bryant Split AC system

Tags: air-conditioning, mini-split

I own an older house with a hot water heat system and I am want to get a Split AC system installed. The setup involves 2 9,000 BTU units, one in each 2nd floor bedroom and a 12,000 BTU unit on the first floor. I am on the fence between the Bryant Legacy system and the Evolution system. I would feel better about paying a premium for the evolution series if I could figure out the difference in efficiency. But I have not been able to find out that information. Both quotes point to the same condenser. So if the difference between the two is based on the condenser, than I might as well go with the cheaper quote. The more expensive units are quieter, but compared with a window AC unit both quotes are going to give me quieter cooling. Thanks.

I added the quote for the split ac units in case anyone is curious.

[image: Quote for Split AC units]

Comment: Personally I get suspicious (and look for brands that provide it) when I can't find the efficiency data that's supposed to be available. What I can say for sure is that in my comparisons the "one head to one compressor" systems all appeared to have better numbers than the "multi-heads to one compressor" systems. But differences between similar-looking systems can be quite large, which is why you want to have the actual numbers to compare.

Comment: To get the efficiency then you will need to test both systems under the same conditions. I doubt you want to buy both so anything else will just be an "educated" guess that you won't know if you could have done better with the other.

Comment: Sounds like what is called a "mini-split"-- a single condensing unit feeding three air handlers each with its own evaporator coil. These are a lot more efficient than the old split system with a single air handler with duct work.

Comment: You make several statements that are counter intuitive to me. The same condenser quieter is more expensive. (I have installed many styles and there is a reason for the $ difference) you really don’t care about the condenser if it is the same and unless going to a higher seer that part is usually the same. What you care about is the compressor and how it is driven. Inverter driven cost more and is quieter and is more efficient but is a mini split the right way to go? Do you have central heat? If you do a high efficiency compressor can be installed and cool the entire house, mini’s can do 1 room

Comment: Like I said we have a hot water boiler. so we will continue to use the hot water boiler to keep warm. We want air conditioning and it seems like all of the multi zone systems that we can get also have heat. Which is fine. I am trying to figure out if the single stage Bryant system will work and work in an efficient way. Having a slightly quieter system would be nice, but not critical.

Comment: @EdBeal I think OP is looking for a ductless system based on "I own an older house with a hot water heat system"

Comment: Gandolf989 , the single stage will work fine but will cost more to run the compressor in these systems are usually on/off , they are noisier yes but historically they breakdown less often. With that said in the last few years the variable speed systems have made big gains in life span and the warranty’s are getting longer also. I have mini splits and thought that I would continue using my old system also for heat but have found that the mini system is cheaper most of the time so having the option can be a good thing. Do you ever save the cost of the high efficiency price premium? Not usually.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Bryant website unavailable to you?

Taken directly from https://www.bryant.com/en/us/products/ductless-systems/

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the compressor they quoted the middle line. I would prefer a 2 stage system. But if it costs between 30% and 50% more money, I guess I'll take the single stage system. It will work better than the window units that I have been using.